# How to force mouseover on all links of a certain class

Tags: jquery, mouseover

I have certain amount of links on my page. Href attribute of each link is associated with an image. So when I hover on a specific link the appropriate image is displayed. I want to make this process automated so that the links get mouse hovered for 5 seconds one after another. I tried this but it does not work:

```
 function circulate(){
  $('.circulating-links').each(function(){
      $(this).trigger('mouseover'); 
  });
 }
```

I've put the above code in $(document).ready() but I can't see any result. But there's a little nuance here though. If I assign the below function to "onmouseover" attribute of those links I get alerts displayed;

```
function showAlert()
{
  alert("Hello");
}
```

To wrap this all: When I mouseover the links with the mouse I can see the images changing. But if I trigger the mouseover event I can't get the same result.

Comment: Need to see your HTML and possibly CSS.  A fiddle would be very helpful.

Comment: I updated my answer with a small example. I assumed that you try to cycle through links of a certain class and display the image from the href.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm look like trigger just calls the handler you set (in your example the alert is displayed). It doesn't set the :hover css style.

jQuery doumentation says:

> trigger() - Execute all handlers and behaviors attached to the matched elements for the given event type.

I am not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but if you just want to cycle through the links of a certain class, get the href and display the image it points to you could do something like this:

Heres a jsfiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/G6AbM

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {color: #000; text-align: center}
            .myLink { text-decoration: underline; }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $.onReady = new function() {
                setTimeout(imageChange, 500);
            }

            var nextImage = 0;
            function imageChange() {
                var elements = $('.myLink');
                $('#currentImage').text(elements[nextImage].href);
                if (++nextImage >= elements.length) {
                    nextImage = 0;
                }               
                setTimeout(imageChange, 500);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#link1.jpg" class="myLink">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#link2.jpg" class="myLink">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#link3.jpg" class="myLink">Link 3</a>
        <br>
        <span id="currentImage">..</span>
    </body>
</html>
```